# Using handlebars to iterate over a complex object

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I have a special array how can I itereate over it ?

It looks like:

```
{
                "0.1.0": {
                    "pictures": {
                        "list": ""
                        },
                    "show": true,
                    "implemented ": false,
                    "percentageDoneVersion": 100,                   
                    "description": "Programmierung ...",
                    "tasks": { 
                    "1":{
                            "percentageDone":10,
                            "description":"Text1..."
                        },
                        "2":{
                            "percentageDone":70,
                            "description":"Text2..."
                        },
                        "3":{
                            "percentageDone":10,
                            "description":"Text3..."
                            }
                    }
                }
```

}

I tried different things, but they did not work out...

Thank you.

Comment: By the phrase, _"I have to skip an element {{versionContent.-.description}}"_, do you mean you don't want to output that attribute? Can you write the complete output you want from this object?

Comment: Your required output isn't quite clear. Could you please provide the desired output or its DOM (not necessarily template but just HTML) in the question? As for your concern on unknown length of the tasks, it can be easily handled by `each` block helper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not fully clear on the requirements but as per provided information, looks like you are looking from something link this:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-template">
  <div class="row" style="">
    <hr>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#versionHeading{{@index}}" href="#versionHeading{{@index}}">{{{body.project.versionHeading}}}</a></h4>
          </div>
          <div id="versionHeading{{@index}}" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p>{{{body.project.versionIntro}}}:</p>
              {{#each body.project.versionContent}}
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#mainVersion{{@index}}" href="#mainVersion{{@index}}">Version {{@key}}</a></h4>
                </div>
                <div id="mainVersion{{@index}}" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>{{{this.description}}}</p>
                    <ul>
                      {{#each this.tasks}}
                      <li>{{@key}}.) {{{this.description}}} (progress ({{this.percentageDone}}% done)</li>
                      {{/each}}
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              {{/each}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Assuming that your provided json data is wrapped inside a body and project structure i.e.

```
{
    "body": {
        "project": {
            "versionContent": {
                  ....
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10591/) from your data and html. You can improve this as required. Version and Tasks both can grow dynamically. I recommend you to go through [this](http://tutorialzine.com/2015/01/learn-handlebars-in-10-minutes/) simple Handlebars tutorial.

Comment: Remove the `wrapper` variable. Instead of `return template(wrapper);`, use `return template(data);`.